# Java RESTfull service don't return list-JSON

Tags: java, rest, service

My RESTfull service return strange JSON which have list of books:

```
[[1,"Book1","Author1"],[2,"Book2","Author2"],[3,"Book3","Author3"]]
```

I think, It should be like that:

```
[     {         "id": 1,    "title": "book",       "author": "author"  },     {        "id": 2,         "title": "book2",         "author": "author2"     } ]
```

Controller:

```
package com.bookService;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/books")
public class BookController implements IBookController {

    @Autowired
    IBookQueries bookQueries;

    public void setBookQueries(IBookQueries bookQueries) {
        this.bookQueries = bookQueries;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)

    public @ResponseBody
    List<Book> getAllBooks() {
         return bookQueries.getAllBooks();
    }   
 }
```

How can i get name-value pair json?

Comment: This is a valid json array. Why it's strange?

Comment: It's a little primitive, but is perfectly legit JSON.

Comment: And it *is* a "List" (JSON array).

Comment: Show us your Book class. Does it extend List or something?

Comment: may be he is confused as it is not having the key-value pair

Comment: @M.Sharma - If so, it's because he doesn't understand JSON, even though one can go to json.org and learn the syntax in 5-10 minutes.

Comment: @HotLicks I think that the OP wants a list of **objects** but is getting a list of **lists**

Comment: did you try APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE

Answer (score -1):

json is wrapperd by brace，and springmvc will use jackson to render an object to json string

so the return type shoud be **Object**

```
public @ResponseBody
Object getAllBooks() {
     return bookQueries.getAllBooks();
}
```

Comment: `List<Book>` is a perfectly fine return type.